# importing iOS-QR-Code-Generator files in an objective-c project : c++ classes dont compile

Tags: c++, objective-c, qr-code

We tried to import in our project the code to generate QRCode iOS-QR-Code-Generator from Kuapay
Although we linked correctly the libpng folder (the #include is found), we have errors on compilation of the qr_ classes
the eror is as follow for by example QR_Encode.h
the class keyword is nor recognized, it seems the project doesn't recognize the file as a c++ file, being an objective-c project
Anyone could help us? 
Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

If the header file contains C++ classes, you'll need to compile the file `#include`ing it as C++ or Objective-C++.  If you have a `.m` file including it, the easiest way to do this is to change the extension to `.mm`

Comment: Thanks for your reply Jeremy, but the file alreadey has the extension .mm

Comment: @user1184785:  make sure the header is not included from anywhere else.  Make sure the class declaration is not inside an `extern "C"` block.